# Recuperar los valores de una clase en C#

Tags: c#

Buenas noches tengo una clase llamada empresa_global, en esta almaceno los datos del cliente los generales, como el nombre de la empresa o el número de la empresa.

Mi problema consiste en decirme que valor es `null`, cuando llamo la función, me podrían dar una mano que es lo malo de este form.

Mi código:

```cs
    public  List<ce_Global_Ecia> mpxListarEmpresa()
        {
            //List<ce_Global_Ecia> LstEmpresa = null;
            List<ce_Global_Ecia> LstEmpresa = new List<ce_Global_Ecia>();
            try
            {
                //List<ce_Global_Ecia> LstEmpresa = new List<ce_Global_Ecia>();
                using (var db = new EntitySIAF())
                {
                    LstEmpresa = (from d in db.MSTCIAs
                                  select new ce_Global_Ecia
                                  {
                                      IdEcia = d.IDECIA,
                                      RazonSocial = d.RZNSOC.ToString(),
                                      Desccia = d.DSCCIA.ToString(),
                                      Tel = d.TELEFO.ToString(),
                                      Ciudad = d.CIUDAD.ToString(),
                                      UrlLog = d.URLLOG.ToString(),
                                      NumRuc = d.NUMRUC.ToString(),
                                  }).ToList();
                }
                //XtraMessageBox.Show("Hay Compañia" + " " + LstEmpresa.Count().ToString());
                return LstEmpresa;
            }
            //return LstEmpresa;

            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString(), "Error - Cargar Datos de la CIA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return LstEmpresa;
        }
```

Luego lo llamo de esta manera:

```csharp
mpxListarempresa ()
```

Y asigno un valor a una variable por ejemplo número de CIA, por último selecciona el nombre de la compañía y mis datos.

Saludos

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mejor tu problema? que problema tenes con los null?

Comment: Necesito o trato de llenar una clase global, con una tabla de configuración del sistema que estoy creando, lleno la clase global con los datos de la empresa, conforme el código que envié, esto lo hago en load del menú principal la llamada a la función que presento, pero cuando trato de recuperar por ejemplo el nombre de la empresa en un formulario o una variable me dice que viene NULL, pero cuando hago el llenado lo hace, creo que estoy llamando mal o se me pierde el registro.

Comment: ok.. ya entendi tu problema.. y no tengo respuesta porque faltaria codigo, pero vos estas llamando a una funcion que devuelve una lista, pero no asignas esa lista a ningun lado en la llamada....

Comment: Cuando yo le asigno a la clase ce_Global_Ecia, los valores de la tabla, alli los asigno, a la clase y lo que mencionas es mi problema, que no se como decirle a la llamada de la lista que me devuelva los valores :
Ahorita hago esto en load de mi menu:
mpxListarempresa () 
Pero alli tengo un par de variable que deseo hacer esta asignacion, pero me da NULL de error
int numeroempresa = ce_Global_Ecia.idecia

Eso quiero hacer pero no me da o es mi error.

Saludos

Comment: Vos estas cargando esos objetos dentro de una lista, que tu metodo devuelve, pero segun lo que contas nadie recibe.. donde esperas que queden esos datos?

Comment: En las variables de la clase global, conforme el codigo de arriba, para mi deberian estar en estas propiedades, luego solo mandarlas a llamar aqui es donde te vuelvo a decir lo mismo, lleno la clase global ahora si caen o se llena los registros quiero recuperarlos para presentarlos en informe o filtros de la empresa, eso es lo que no he podido hacer, recuperarlos.
Saludos

Comment: Que clase global? Yo no veo ninguna clase global en el codigo que estas mostrando...

Comment: Gracias por tu interes en ayudarme, pero veo que no se entiendo mi problema, a la clase que me refieron es a la que lleno:
public class ce_Global_Ecia
 Solo queria pasar la tabla en esta lista, recuperar los datos para que fuera reusable, en todo el sistema, pero no se pudo, gracias amigo, dare por cerrado este punto.

Comment: Que a una clase le escribas Global, no la hace global. Eso es lo que trato de decirte.. tu clase Global, la estas cargando en una lista, dentro de un metodo, que solo vive en ese metodo, y ese metodo devuelve una lista, que no estas recibiendo en ningun lado, que tiene la clase que vos llamas "global" pero que de global, solo tiene el nombre. Yo te entiendo, lo que pasa es que tu codigo no refleja lo que vos decis que estas haciendo...